# Phonegap/Onsen/AngularJS Remove Page after Pagechange

Tags: angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I´m developing an App with Cordova Onsen-UI and AngularJS.

I have several pages in my application.

I change the page with that command:

```
$scope.ons.navigator.pushPage('msg_det.html', { animation: 'slide' });
```

I´ve noticed the following:
If I call the same page with the same command again, the old page still exist.

(I have a html element

```
for example: <img id="test" src="sadf.png" />
```

with an ID. At the first time, the access by id works.

```
$("#test").css("left", "20px");
```

After the second time it is not been working anymore.)
That is a sign, that the id still exists a second time.

Is there a chance to build the page "msg_det" new and delete the old one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you need to check it manually

`$scope.ons.navigator.getPages()` gives you all the pages that currently exist, so check if your page already exist call the `destroy()` on old page.

for more info take a look at http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#PageNavigation

Comment: Yes, pages are not automatically removed from the stack, only when using `navigator.popPage()`, `navigator.resetToPage()` or similar. Removing pages manually is not very common, but yes, `navigator.getPages()` or `navigator.getCurrentPage()` work for that.

Comment: Ok. Thank you.

For my requirements, I can simply replace the pushPage() with resetToPage().
So I never get multiple pages.

Speaks anythings against that?

Comment: No, if you're going to remove all pages anyway you might as well use `resetToPage()`.

Comment: @AndreasArgelius would you lead us to a best practice for this?